# How to handle large number of requests in scrapy?

Tags: python, memory, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm crawling around 20 million urls. But before the request is actually made the process gets killed due to excessive memory usage (4 GB RAM). How can I handle this in scrapy so that the process doesn't gets killed ?

```
class MySpider(Spider):
name = "mydomain"
allowed_domains = ["mydomain.com"]
urls = []
for d in range(0,20000000):
    link = "http://example.com/"+str(d)
    urls.append(link)
start_urls = urls

def parse(self, response):
    yield response
```

Comment: what's the error scrapy outputs?

Comment: Just `killed` after some time. I monitored the memory usage and saw when available memory reduces to 100 mb or lesser it just gets killed.

Comment: it would be helpful if you share logs.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the workaround.
Add this method to your spider.

```
def start_requests(self):
    for d in range(1,26999999):
        yield scrapy.Request("http://example.com/"+str(d), self.parse)
```

you dont have to specify the start_urls in the starting.

It will start generating URLs and start sending asynchronous requests and the callback will be called when the scrapy gets the response.In the start the memory usage will be more but later on it will take constant memory.

Along with this you can use

```
scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1
```

By using this you can pause the spider and resume it any time by using the same command

and in order to save CPU (and log storage requirements) 
use

```
LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'
```

in settings.py of the scrapy project.

Answer (score 0):

I believe creating a big list of urls to use as `start_urls` may be causing the problem.

How about doing this instead?

```
class MySpider(Spider):
name = "mydomain"
allowed_domains = ["mydomain.com"]

start_urls = ["http://example.com/0"]

def parse(self, response):
    for d in xrange(1,20000000):
        link = "http://example.com/"+str(d)
        yield Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_link)

def parse_link(self, response):
    yield response
```

Comment: It will also get killed as scrapy will queue the request object in the memory. And it will ask for more memory when the limit is over.

Comment: Do try it though. I've tried scraping of this scale before and pulled it off. Scrapy scaled well in those situations

Comment: Maybe *micro optimization*, but you should use `xrange` instead of `range` if you want to spare some memory.

Comment: @Rahul, according to [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html), if you set the `'JOBDIR'` setting a disk queue will be used. With it you can discard the queue size as the cause of you problem.

Comment: Yup. Read that earlier. I was trying it while using the start_url method only but the same result. Let  me give it a try with this one.

Comment: @RoshanJossey please change `range` to `xrange`. This is a memory-based question so your answer should be tied to that.

Comment: Done. Thanks for improving the answer @memoselyk, Andrés Pérez-Albela H.

Comment: can anyone help me? I am also facing the same problem.

Comment: @MuditJuneja: Could you elaborate?

Comment: @sudo I also have about 3 M links to append in start_urls.But it is giving Memory error and I am not able to find any other work around.

Comment: @MuditJuneja: Why are you not able to use the solution I've explained in my answer? (generating the links in the first parse method scrapy excecutes).

Comment: @sudo your solution is also giving the memory error.